# npm install hangs on my network, but works on others

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, npm

I’m having this issue with npm where I cannot install the packages in my `package.json` on my home network. I tried countless “fixes” (including modifying the registry to http instead of https, modifying the proxy and https-proxy, using unsafe-perm, installing the packages individually, etc.) but none of them seem to work. I decided to try installing them while connected to my phone’s LTE hotspot and miraculously it worked normally. Now my next issue is, what could be causing this?

When I install on my network, it starts to slow down and then completely stops and hangs (on a random package). After a few tries, I was able to install yarn, and could install my dependencies with it.

Extra info:

- I tried this on multiple node/npm versions but still hangs
- Verbose install on npm doesn’t give much information, but usually hangs here `[.....] \ extract:rxjs: sill extract rxjs@6.3.3 extracted to /home/abbas/git/abbas-yadollahi/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-36adb757 160099ms`
- My network is fine as far as I know (50/10 up/down and I’m on LAN)

Comment: Does your IPv6 network work "quickly"? If you go to http://ip6only.me/ do you see either an error message or an actual webpage quickly?

Comment: @Ferrybig The site doesn't load, it can't find the IP